# Paypal API Setup for Paypal Pro

Tags: api, paypal

I am having difficulty figuring out how to set up the API for the Paypal pro accounts. They list it as the NVP/SOAP account. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/apps101/

I have researched this and created a sandbox test API app for the sandbox credentials. I am just unsure of where the API doc is that I need to include and then what else I need for it. I found this, but it confuses me even more. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/ ...

I am unsure of what I need to put where and how to even process this. I have integrated the authorize.net API and there was a base template for it that required only modification and it was very straight forward.

Could anyone provide me with some insight to how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/gs_PayPalPaymentsPro/?mark=paypal%20pro

You need to first setup the authentication parameters

PWD : // password

SIGNATURE : // signature

USER : // user id

VERSION

and then calls the  different paypal methods like DoDirectPayment etc with their list of parameters..
Refer the documentation for the individual paypal methods and their list of parameters.

Also first create a paypal sandbox account to get the API credentials

Comment: I have the sandbox account and credentials. I just don't know what to put in my file now to go along with it.